# Does distribution derivative generated by $C^{\infty}$ function forces the distribution to be compactly supported?

Tags: measure-theory, distribution-theory

Let $\phi \in C_C^{\infty}(\Bbb R)$. Then there exists a $\psi \in C_C^{\infty}(\Bbb R)$ such that $\psi' = \phi \iff \int_\Bbb R \phi = 0$. This is quite easy to be proved. From this it follows that if distribution derivative is zero, then the distribution generated by a constant function. Does it also follow that if distribution derivative is generated by $C^{\infty}$,then the distribution is compactly supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A distribution derivative can be $C^\infty$ without being compactly supported.  It can be, for example, $1$.  Remember, a function corresponds to a distribution if the function is locally integrable (it has an integral $<\infty$ on compact sets).  Look at Rudin *Functional Analysis* 6.11-6.14.

Caveat: I'm not sure what you mean by "if distribution derivative is *generated by* $C^\infty$." I took you to mean that it corresponds to a function in $C^\infty$.  Maybe you mean $C_c^\infty$?  In that case, the answer is yes; look at Rudin 6.22, and consider that the integral of the product of two $C_c^\infty$ functions with nonoverlapping supports is zero.

Comment: Distribution derivative $T'$ for $ T \in C_c^{\infty}'(\Bbb R) $ is given by $T'(\phi) = \int f \phi$ where $f$ is a $ C^{\infty} $ function. Now I should show that $T$ can be extended to $ C^{\infty}'(\Bbb R) $.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "$T$ can be extended to $C^\infty{}'({\mathbb R})$."  $T$ in your example is the distribution corresponding to a $C_c^\infty$ function.  Its derivative will also be in $C_c^\infty$.

Comment: That is exactly the class of distributions with compact support. My question is if the derivative of a distribution is generated by $C^\infty$ function then does the distribution belongs to the class of distribution with compact support.